# GnuTLS API with Windows

Tags: c, windows, dll, gnutls

I'm trying to use the GnuTLS API on a window machine, sadly it will not work. I downloaded the latest precompiled version for Windows gnutls-3.3.9-w32.zip.

Each time I call a GnuTLS function, my program wont work probably. For testing there are only two lines of code:

```
printf ("hello");
gnutls_global_init();
```

it will build without errors but it won't print "hello", if I delete the second line it works. So there must be a mistake within the usage of GnuTLS.

I included the libgnutls-28.dll

```
gcc "-LC:GnuTLS\\gnutls-3.3.9-w32\\bin" -o Test.exe test.o -llibgnutls-28
```

Do I have to link the libgnutls.dll.a file somehow?

Comment: force a buffer flush, since the tls stuff may be killing your terminal. e.g. `printf("hello\n");`.

Comment: thx, but didn't work for me

Comment: Have you checked the return of _gnutls_global_init()_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Do I have to link the libgnutls.dll.a file somehow?*.

Yes.  *Linking* libraries is required for building.  But you said it is building okay...  In support of what Marc B was saying, test to see whether your printf is working:

```
printf ("hello");
getchar();                    // to stop execution before calling init  
//Check the return of your init function
status = gnutls_global_init();//On success, GNUTLS_E_SUCCESS (zero) is returned,
```

*For testing there are only two lines of code:*
***Add a few more*** to check status of your init function:

```
if(status < 0)                //otherwise an error code is returned.
{
     //handle error
}
```

Click  ***[gnutls_global_init](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gnutls_global_init)***  for man page.

***Another thing to check*** is where you have the .dll located.

Ensure it is visible to the executable at run-time.  Put it in either in the .exe. directory, or in the $SYSTEM$ directory, for your system.

One gottcha for people is ***[WoW64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64)***.  The Windows system directory for 32 bit applications on Windows 7 (or 8) is c:\windows\sysWoW64\ (i.e. not c:\windows\system32).  ***Ironically***, the system directory for ***64 bit apps is*** c:\windows\system32\ .

Comment: couldn't read out the status first, but thanks to your second tip with bad located .dlls I figuered out that appearently some .dlls have been missing. copyed them to the .exe directory and it finaly worked! Thanks!